# multirow table formatting

Tags: tables

I need to format a table like this:
[image]
I've got as far as getting this:
[image]

Latex code is here:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\rule{9cm}{2pt}
\makebox[2.9cm]{\small{Xxxx}} \rule{0.5pt}{1cm} \makebox[3.5cm]{\small{Xxxxxxxxx}} \rule{0.5pt}{1cm} \makebox[1cm]{\small{Xxxxx}}
\rule{9cm}{0.5pt}
\makebox[2.9cm]{\small{Xxxxxx Xxxxxxxx}} \rule{0.5pt}{1cm} \makebox[3.4cm]{\small{Xxxxxx Xxxxxx}} \rule{0.5pt}{1cm} \makebox[1cm]{Xxx}
\rule{9cm}{0.5pt}
\makebox[2.8cm]{\small{Xxxxxxxxxxx Xxxx}} \rule{0.5pt}{1cm} \makebox[3.5cm]{\small{Xx xx Xxxxxxxxxxx (N)}} \rule{0.5pt}{1cm} \makebox[1cm]{\small{Xxxx}}
\phantom{Xxxxxxxxxx Xxxxx} \rule{0.5pt}{1cm} \makebox[3.5cm]{\small{Xxxxx Xxx (X)}} \rule{0.5pt}{1cm} \makebox[1cm]{\small{x}}
\rule{9cm}{0.5pt}
\makebox[2.9cm]{\small{Xxxxxx Xx Xxxx}} \rule{0.5pt}{1cm} \makebox[3.7cm]{\small{Xxxxxx Xxxxxxxxx}} \rule{0.5pt}{1cm} \makebox[1cm]{\small{xx}}
\rule{9cm}{2pt}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Someone kindly help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This is not *exactly* the standard way to make a table in LaTeX. Why do vertically aligned boxes have different widths? And do you really want to have discontinuous vertical lines?

Comment: i know the standard way is declaring columns and putting data with & symbol. But I need exact formatting of first image.

Comment: You didn't completely answer my questions: what is the difference of widths in the same columns supposed to be for?

Comment: but there is no difference in width of same columns in first image (which i want end resullt to be like). yes there is difference in 2nd image, it just happend, i tried to make it better but couldn't get desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with `booktabs` and `makecell`. The height of the vertical rules is realised by inserting at the beginning of every cell of the first column an invisible rule of the prescribed height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,makecell, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering\small\sffamily%
  \setlength\aboverulesep{1ex}
  \setlength\belowrulesep{1ex}
  \renewcommand{\cellalign}{lc}
  \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.5pt}
  \begin{tabular}{ >{\rule[-0.35cm]{0pt}{1cm}}m{2.9cm}|m{3.7 cm}|m{1cm}}
    \toprule[2pt]
    Xxxx & Xxxxxxxxx & Xxxxx \\
    \midrule[0.5pt]
    Xxxxxx Xxxxxxxx & Xxxxxx Xxxxxx & Xxx \\
    \midrule[0.5pt]%
    Xxxxxxxxxxx Xxxx & \makecell{Xx xx Xxxxxxxxxxx (N) \\ Xxxxx Xxx (X)} & \makecell{Xxxx \\ x} \\%
    \midrule[0.5pt]%
    Xxxxxx Xx Xxxx & Xxxxxx Xxxxxxxxx & xx \\
    \bottomrule[2pt]%
  \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]